# Unable to install Ocaml on windows using diskuv installer

Tags: windows, ocaml, ocamlbuild

I am unable to install Ocaml on windows, I downloaded the diskuv exe file, but when I run this I get following error plus some messages, I have tried this multiple times using admin rights as well, but unble to install it.

Now it says where.exe is not recognised, but it's there I can fire it with command prompt same goes for pwsh.exe, So I am clueless now

Here is what I have tried:

1. I removed the "DiskuvOCaml" folder then tried reinstalling again using admin rights , it doesn't work
2. I am using windows 11 and tried with another system of windows 10, windows 10 works fine for installing ocaml, utop and other ocaml commands are working using same process
3. I restarted the system and did the same process many times, It is unable to get installed on my system with windows 11. Any thoughts , why is it happening and how can I fix this? Appreciate much help here.

Error with messages:

> 'where.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
>
> Neither 'pwsh.exe' nor 'powershell.exe' were found. Make sure you have
> PowerShell installed.
>
> FATAL [a0d16230]. A transient failure occurred.
>
> Root cause: The conformant command had exit code 1:
> C:\Users\prade\AppData\Local\Temp\7z4F7D9FCC\sg\network-ocamlcompiler\windows_x86_64\setup-userprofile.bat
> -AllowRunAsAdmin
> -InstallationPrefix
> C:\Users\prade\AppData\Local\Programs\DISKUV~1
> -MSYS2Dir
> C:\Users\prade\AppData\Local\Programs\DISKUV~1\tools\MSYS2
> -OpamExe
> C:\Users\prade\AppData\Local\Programs\DISKUV~1\bin\OPAM-R~1.EXE
> -DkmlPath
> C:\Users\prade\AppData\Local\Temp\7Z4F7D~1\sg\NETWOR~1\WINDOW~1\dkmldir
> -GlobalCompileDir
> C:\Users\prade\AppData\Local\Temp\7Z4F7D~1\sg\STAGIN~1\generic
> -NoDeploymentSlot -DkmlHostAbi
> windows_x86_64 -TempParentPath
> C:\Users\prade\AppData\Local\Temp\PA308E~1
> -SkipProgress -SkipMSYS2Update